# Program executes before await finishes in Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

OK, So I am beginner and trying to learn Async/Await concept. Now I understood now how Async Await works and wrote below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
   CallHttp();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

static public async void CallHttp()
{
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.crowdin.com/");
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("URL");
     using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"SomeLoc\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
      await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
   }
```

Ok, this code works fine, but as soon as I remove the Thread.SLeep it stops working, only valid explanation is that my program finishes execution before my await gets processed.

Doubt: But I am not seeing this detail to be mentioned in any of the articles, is this not a genuine doubt? Am I missing some concept here? So whenever I apply Async await I have to MAKE SURE that my entire program waits for that await to finish?

I can use something like `Task.WaitAll()` but won't that again make my program `Hold/Non Responsive`. Please guide me.  I don't see any article telling this RED FLAG in any example they have shown, why so?

Edit:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = CallHttp();
        }
        static public async Task CallHttp()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.crowdin.com/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("URL");
            using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
                await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"\alpha\test.zip", @"\beta");
        }
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/08/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-console-app-main-method/

Comment: A negative vote.. Seriously..!

Comment: Short answer: no, you have not understood how async/await works. You need to read how async void methods work

Comment: async Main in C# 7.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main

Comment: *"I can use something like Task.WaitAll()"* - That certainly sounds reasonable when you want to wait for tasks to finish.  *"but won't that again make my program Hold/Non Responsive"* - I don't see why you would think that.  Have you tried?  Is there some observable problem you can describe?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: In Edit Section: I returned an empty task instead of `Void`.

Comment: @Unbreakable: *"I returned an empty task"* - But you never await that task in the caller.

Comment: @Unbreakable And now who waits for `CallHttp` to finish?

Comment: @David: So that's what so I NEED TO MAKE sure eventually that "My Main Thread" does not finishes its execution right? that is what I am asking that when I do Asyn/Await , I do need to make sure that my Main Thread does not DIE. Am I right?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: So Lesson is I can use all async await I want, but I need to make sure my main thread does not die before them.

Comment: @Unbreakable: You need to await tasks if you want them to complete, yes.  (Well, if you want to observe their completion.)  Exiting a thread or an application will cause that thread or application to exit.

Comment: @David:  May be its something so obvious that I dont see it mentioned anywhere, that Make sure your overall application is not so small that it finishes before Await is done. Just saying. But now I get the point.

Comment: @David: Just one last question, so every async await method I write, I need to make sure I call that with the Await keyword. Because this sitaution that I have can occur anywhere right? Becasue my main application can always finish before my await is done with the execution. If this question is too silly, you can ignore. thanks!

Comment: @Unbreakable: As you read about async/await, you may encounter the phrase "async all the way down".  That's basically what that means.  If a method invokes an asynchronous operation, it should await that operation and should itself be an asynchronous method to be awaited.  The actual asynchronous things are generally happening at the lowest level (physical device I/O), and the highest level (the application host) needs to be aware of them.  Never hide the fact that something is asynchronous or an application host won't know to await it.

Comment: @David: I see.. thanks a ton!

Comment: @Unbreakable: Anecdote to illustrate this... At a previous client I worked with their team had this large library of internal code that they used as a standard in all of their many, many applications.  Mostly WinForms apps or similar.  While I was there we were going to make use of a variety of other application types, including scheduled console apps, cloud Web API microservices, etc.  In my code their "core library" was failing left and right.  Turns out they had a ton of async that wasn't awaited.  They simply never noticed in their WinForms apps because the app wasn't being closed.

Comment: @David: Now this anecdote makes me think that I am on the same page with you and I understood what you are trying to tell, and other people have also encountered this issue. Glad that I know this now at an early stage of my career. Thank you so much!

Comment: @David: I dont know if you will agree with me but most of the basic examples I am seeing on internet, the call to async has been made directly without the await keyword, and the autor has used 'console.readline' or something to make sure that Async method gets enough time to retrieve its value. I think this is also one of the reason I was confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179287/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-david).

Comment: @Unbreakable: I have no doubt that there are many examples of lazy programming online :)  (I’ve written a few myself over the years, truth be told.)  People are often content with what they have once they’ve “gotten it to work” even without understanding it.  For async/await I would recommend any article, example, and even Stack Overflow answer by Stephen Cleary.  He dives into the underlying concepts to really know how and why async does what it does, and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not awaiting on `CallHttp()` in your Main method. Wait on your task by using `GetAwaiter().GetResult` or calling `.Wait()` on `CallHttp`. It will not block your program infinitely and will only wait until the task is complete.